# AWS Security Group Best Practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

Good day,

If one is provisioning an EC2 instance (serverA) that receives TCP traffic on port 8000 from a handful of yet to be provisioned EC2 instances (serverB, serverC, etc), what is the best practice for configuring security groups on serverA?

```
Security group: serverA_sg
Source: CIDR block that encompass serverB/C and any future instances of the same type
Port range: 8000

CIDR block would have to be at least /24 due to the fluidity of the environment.
```

or

```
Security group: serverA_sg
Source: serverA_sg
Port range: 8000

Then assign "serverA_sg" to serverB/C when they are provisioned? I assume the negative here is that the "client" instances will also then be available on 8000.
```

or something else entirely?

Thank you!

Comment: Are servers B/C going to be in the same VPC as server A?

Comment: Instances will be in the same VPC.

Comment: Create an empty security group representing inbound clients on port 8000 for server A. When you launch servers B and C, add them to that security group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close with your 2nd option. The best practice would be:

```
Rule1:
Security group: serverA_sg
Source: serverB_sg
Port range: 8000

Rule2:
Security group: serverA_sg
Source: serverC_sg
Port range: 8000
```

Then assign "serverB_sg" to serverB, and assign "serverC_sg" to serverC.

---

Best practices within the VPC is to use security group references instead of CIDR blocks. And each logical group of servers should have their own separate security group to control exactly which ports are open, and to allow changing the ports allowed in that group without affecting other server groups.

Comment: Understood. I'm confused about the ordering. If serverA is the only server presently in existence should its security group use itself as the source, or should the provisioning of the security group wait until serverB+ is online?

Comment: You can provision a security group without any rules, and add rules later once the other groups exist.